# Equivalence classes of "$x \sim y \Longleftrightarrow x -y $ is rational".

Tags: equivalence-relations

Given the equivalence relation $x \sim y \Longleftrightarrow x -y $ is rational on the interval $[0,1)$.

How do we reason* that there are uncountably infinite number of equivalence classes?

*A rigorous proof is not required but still welcome.

**Edit**

The equivalence relation on $[0,1)$ given by $x∼y⇔x−y$ is rational.

Comment: If the set of equivalence classes is countable, then $(0,1)$ is the countable union of countable sets and therefore is countable, which is a contradiction.

Comment: @CameronBuie - Thanks for the correction. Qns edited.

Comment: No problem at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $x\in[0,1)$, show that $x/\sim$ is countable (because every element is of the form $x+q$ for some unique rational $q$).

If there would be countably many equivalence classes then $[0,1)$ would be the countable union of countable sets, which is not the case.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say we have $\kappa$ many equivalence classes, each classes having $\omega$ number of elements (countably infinite), so we have
$$c=|[0,1)|=\kappa\cdot\omega$$
and, as among cardinals, $\kappa\cdot\omega=\max(\kappa,\omega)$, we get that $\kappa=c=$ continuum.